# Rails forcing the file name with send_data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've a Clients controller:

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @clients = Client.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.text do
        file_name = "clients_emails.txt"
        send_data @clients.pluck(:email).join('; '), file_name: file_name
      end 
    end 
  end
end
```

There is a link in the application that points to this controller index action  :

```
link_to "Extract Email List", clients_path(format: "text")
```

When I press the link the file is automatically downloaded but the name of the file is **clients.text**

It looks like **:file_name** option is being ignored.

Is there a way with send_data to force the browser to create a file with a given name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it with `filename`:

```
send_data @clients.pluck(:email).join('; '), filename: file_name
```

Comment: HA - I love this small bloody typos:P TY mate!